# Wordpress: footer is cut off in page only

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

I'm asking for help for a very odd behaviour the footer of a Wordpress theme is having: it looks good overall (http://gwyneth-paltrow.org/test/) but, if I click on a page,
it appears cut off (http://gwyneth-paltrow.org/test/?page_id=2).

It looks like the footer "takes" its width from the page's width and it's also decentered. I honestly don't know if the problem lies on the CSS (but if so, I should encounter the same trouble on the whole site, instead it happens on pages only) or in the coding of the the page.php file. I'm far from being an expert, but if I had to bet, I'd say the latter because that's when the issue pops up.

I'm adding the coding of the page.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div  id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="height:95px; background: url(images/title-nodate.png);valign:top;">
<table style="width:616px;">
<tr>
<td style="width:616px;"><div class="title-nodate"><?php the_title(); ?></div></td>
</tr></table>
<tr>
<td style="width:616px; background: url(images/content.png);">
<div class="content">
<?php the_content('Continue reading &raquo;'); ?></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:616px; height:52px; background: url(images/content-bottom.png);"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an unclosed `<div>` that is causing the display issues on page 2. See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  gwyneth-paltrow.org test ?page_id=2 - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//gwyneth-paltrow.org/test/%3Fpage_id%3D2&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code and compare to the test page. You need to edit/add that closing tag in your page template.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I thought I closed that <div> in the index.php file, as I added a </div> right before the <?php get_footer(); ?>. Anyway, I removed the </div> from index.php and moved it on page.php right before the <?php get_footer(); ?> but unfortunately the issue seems to still be there.

Comment: Nevermind, it worked! For some reason the PC I was writing form did not refreshed the page properly, but it actually worked. Basically, in order to see the footer properly, next to the </table> I added 2 closing div </div>. Thank you very much!